# Facebook Albums API Issues

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I've been using the Facebook API to pull a list of Albums and photos from the service for years now. Around September of last year, the API calls have stopped pulling the latest albums. The albums from September prior are easy to retrieve and work great. However, anything since that time cannot be pulled. Does anyone know what may have changed since that time?

Heres the endpoint that I have been using...

https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me/albums?fields=id,name,type,description,link,cover_photo,photo_count,created_time&limit=5&access_token=

I also tested this in the Graph API Explorer in thee FB developer tools online and get the same result.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated as. I have not been able to locate any information on their API docs about this.

Thanks,
Wil